# Override default PowerShell PWD alias only within a script

Tags: powershell

I'd like to override the default `pwd` alias to return just the exact `Path`, and the change should only occur within the script. Typically, the `pwd` (Path only) it can be achieved with the following command:

```
(Get-Location).Path
```

How can I set this as the new default `pwd` alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function to return the value you want:

```
function Get-PathOnly
{
  return (Get-Location).Path
}
```

Set the `pwd` alias to that function:

```
Set-Alias pwd Get-PathOnly -Scope Script
```

Comment: +1 Thank you! Additional info for others: To set the alias only within the script, add `-Scope Script`, e.g `Set-Alias pwd Get-PathOnly -Scope Script`

Comment: @Küroro You're welcome! Added the `-Scope` param to the answer :)